# Stop Excel switching to "Object" view

Tags: debugging, vba, excel

I'm debugging this VBA script and every time I hit RESET (little blue square) it takes me out of "code view" and puts me back in "object view." It is infuriating. Is there some way to stop this behavior?

Screenshots:

Object View: [image: http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8101/objectview.jpg]

Code View: [image: http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/6628/codeview.jpg]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of "object view"?

Comment: You can easily see what I mean by opening excel, opening the VBA editor (alt+f11), then right-clicking on "ThisWorkbook" or "Sheet", or any other entry in the project explorer, and selecting "View Object"

Comment: Oh man is this ever annoying with userforms...

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have Excel. Help me with a screenshot, I will try and see if I can think of what the reason could be.

Comment: I have added some screenshots

Comment: Close all the forms from "object view" before you start debugging. Ideally, close all files (press Ctrl + F4) to close all the code/design view before you debug. Let me know of your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initiating execution of the script from Code View, rather than the UserForm, will cause Excel to return to Code View after ending the script.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question, rather than the currently selected answer? It sounds more fitting.

Comment: I stumbled upon the answer, but I have to wait one more day before I can answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the behavior. You can press <kbd>F7</kbd> to go to code view which might make it slightly less annoying.

Comment: You could use an [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to automate the pressing of f7 based possibly based on pixel matching features specific to the Object View?

Comment: So aggravating. Not a bad idea on the autohotkey. I may do that.